# Magento 1.* SUPEE 9767 "Reversed or previously applied patch detected

Tags: magento-1.9, patches, supee-9767

I am currently trying to apply patch SUPEE 9767 v2 to one of our legacy sites running Magento 1.9.2.4, however when I try to run it, I receive the following:

```
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/multishipping/addresses.phtml
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/multishipping/billing.phtml
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/multishipping/shipping.phtml
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method.phtml
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/page.xml
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/multishipping/addresses.phtml
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/multishipping/billing.phtml
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
```

The errors seem to indicate that the patch has already been applied, but according to MageReport.com, that isn't the case. I've tried diff-ing the files to core, but can't seem to figure out what's wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think you already applied v1 for this patch

So download v1 patch from magento and revert that patch by following command

```
 sh patchname.sh -R
```

and then apply V2 patch

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I had a site where I applied in that order patches `SUPEE-9767-v1` and `SUPEE-10266`.

I tried to revert the patch `SUPEE-9767-v1`, and ran into a (not so visible) error on the first chunk while reverting (you may have to scroll up to see it, because the lower part displays a "ok" message).

There was a conflict with some files patched in the `SUPEE-10266`, so the patch wasn't really reverted. If you try to apply the `v2` patch, you get exactly your error.

Don't forget to first revert `SUPEE-10266`, and then `SUPEE-9767-v1`.

Then, you will be able to apply the `SUPEE-9767-v2`.

Remember to check any other patches you may have applied after the `SUPEE-9767-v1` to revert them in the right order.

Check the file `app/etc/applied.patches.list` to see details of the applied patches.